# What was the gravel-like surface that Kylo Ren put his mask on?

Tags: star-wars

What was the gravel-like surface that Kylo Ren put his mask on?

It seemed strange to me, both that there was this large dedicated storage surface for his mask in the interrogation room and that it had this rocky, dirt/gravel like substance in it.

I could be mistaken but I seem to think he also had a storage surface like this for Darth Vader's mask.

[image]

Comment: Just some dirt I got from the garden.

Comment: @KyloRen You thought if you planted it then you might be able to grow a few more?

Comment: Nah, was not really thinking at the time. Actually it is a pain to clean the crap off the helmet when I need to put back on, the dirt is like hair after a haircut and not taking a shower, really itchy.

Comment: I thought they were the ashes of Darth Vader. Kylo Ren retrieved the helmet from wherever Vader's remains were buried after the cremation, he could well have brought some ashes too. No confirmation of that though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/04/05/star-wars-force-awakens-jj-abrams-kylo-ren-ashes) interview with J.J. Abrams:

> “The backstory is, that that table has the ashes of the enemies he’s killed,” Abrams says.

So there's a somewhat out-of-universe answer (not technically canon, unless perhaps it is mentioned in the novelization).

EDIT: By @ruakh's suggestion, this answer is better described as **in-universe** but still **not technically canon**

Comment: Thank you. Let's hope there's no nearby ventilation LOL. OK seriously, let's give a little more time for anyone who may have more details and if no one else submits a better answer I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't a quote from the director be canon?

Comment: @RedCaio IMHO, word from the director is more like "Word of God". To be canon, it would have to be specifically mentioned in a canon source such as a movie or a book. But it's close to canon.

Comment: Well that's very lame. I was hoping for Vader's ashes; "ya, this is d00ds i killed, f33r me" isn't exactly teeming with character.

Comment: @RedCaio A more pedantic reason would be that "canon" only consists of published works that are approved by the Lucasfilm Story Group. Interviews with the director don't fall under that, so they in and of themselves are not canon. Granted, J.J. Abrams is commenting on a published work that *was* approved and that he helped create, hence DBPriGuy's comment that "it's close to canon". But the work does not sufficiently explain this on its own and if another canon source contradicted his interview, it would take precedence.

Comment: @kungphu it is consistent with Ren's characterization though ;)

Comment: @RedCaio: In general when managing a fictional property, if the owner of the property is going to have a notion of "canon" at all, it means that something canonical "isn't allowed" to be contradicted in future releases. At least that if it is, there must be some explanation provided of why what appeared to be true actually isn't. So for some properties the director's word *ex cathedra* might be considered canon, for other properties they don't want future writers to be constrained by the director's off-hand remarks, and so don't hold them as canonical.

Comment: @Gusdor Oh, no argument from me there. :)

Comment: I'm on board with your statement that this is "not technically canon", but I'm confused by your statement that it's an "out-of-universe answer". What's "out-of-universe" about it? The prop is obviously not made from the ashes of the actor's enemies . . .

Comment: @ruakh What I mean is that the fact the ashes Kylo puts his mask in are the ashes of his enemies is not something that is explained in any canon material. Although I guess I might be the one abusing the term "out-of-universe" since it could just as easily be canon

Comment: @DBPriGuy: Yes, I think you've misunderstood the "in-universe"-vs.-"out-of-universe" distinction. An "in-universe" answer is one that makes sense (or aims to make sense) within the context of the fictional universe, whereas an "out-of-universe" answer appeals to the real world. For example, Han Solo's misuse of "parsec" in *A New Hope* can be explained out-of-universe as a writer's mistake, and in-universe by various rationalizations about why the character might have said that. Such rationalizations do not appear in canon, but are attempts at an "in-universe" explanation.

Comment: @ruakh I made an edit noting the mistake. Thanks much